# How to set the Target Bot API for SWTBot

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I'm using SWTBot 2.3.0 and I want to record actions which are executed on a Grid object.

I saw that the recorder has this select button [Target Bot API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/866Hp.png).

I already have the nebula plugins in my run configuration.

Do I have to add the org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid jar in order to record such an object? If so, where do I put it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no "rule" for detecting events for the Nebula extension and generating code test from them. You can consider writing and contributing such rules to SWTBot: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Generator#Extending_it